# Produce List with intent items from row text

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have some row text. I want from this text to create Events and intent activities, put them on lists and then import them on a db. Let me be more specific. Let’s assume that I have the following sentence:
“***On Party1 we will take some drinks, eat very good food and play ps3 games. On Party2 we will do karaoke and dance with hip hop songs.***”

My desire output want to be:

**Event 1: Party1**

```
Activitie1: take some drinks
Activitie2: eat very good food
Activitie3: play ps3 games
```

**Event2: Party2**

```
Activitie1: do karaoke
Activitie2: dance with hip hop songs
```

What I have done until now, is allowing special characters “#,*” . So when I have * I produce an event and when I have # I produce an activity. As a result I can produce events and activities but I can’t match them. I need to find a way to match(intent) the produced elements. My code:

```
string astring = Convert.ToString(lblrowtext.Text);          
if (astring.IndexOf("#") >= 0 || astring.IndexOf("*") >= 0)          
{               
  string[] Eventsarray;            
  string[] Activitiessarray;            
  List<string> listofEvents = new List<string>();            
  List<string> listofActivities = new List<string>();            
  Activitiessarray = Regex.Matches(astring, @"#([^\*#]*)").Cast<Match>()
                          .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();   
  Eventsarray = Regex.Matches(astring, @"\*([^\*#]*)").Cast<Match>()
                     .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();             
  if (Activitiessarray != null)            
  {                
     if (Activitiessarray.Count() > 0)             
     {
        listofActivities = new List<string>(Activitiessarray);
        ViewState["listofActivities"] = listofActivities;
        Repeater1.DataSource = listofActivities;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
     }

     if (Eventsarray != null)
     {
        if (Eventsarray.Count() > 0)
        {
           listofEvents = new List<string>(Eventsarray);
           ViewState["listofEvents"] = listofEvents;
           Repeater2.DataSource = listofEvents;
           Repeater2.DataBind();
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this like below:

```
  private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var updationIndex = 0;
        const string inputString = "On *Party1 #we will take some drinks, #eat very good food and #play ps3 games.# ";
        Func<string, char, char, string> getMyString = (givenString, skipTill, takeTill) =>
            {
                var opString =
                    new string(
                        givenString.ToCharArray()
                                   .SkipWhile(x => x != skipTill)
                                   .Skip(1)
                                   .TakeWhile(x => x != takeTill)
                                   .ToArray());

                updationIndex = inputString.IndexOf(givenString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                + opString.Length;

                return opString;
            };

        var eventName = getMyString(inputString, '*', '#');
        Console.WriteLine("Event" + eventName);
        Console.WriteLine("Activities: ");
        while (updationIndex < inputString.Length)
        {
           var activity = getMyString(inputString.Remove(0, updationIndex), '#', '#');
           Console.WriteLine(activity);
           if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity))
           {
               break;
           }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Event class to which you add Activities. Each time you encounter a *****, create a new Event instance.

Psuedo-C#:

```
class Event 
{
    string Description;
    List<Activity> Activities;
}

class Activity
{
    string Description;
}

List<Event> ParseEventLines(IEnumerable<string> allLines)
{
    var result = new List<Event>();

    Event currentEvent = null;

    foreach (var line in allLines)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("*"))
        {
            currentEvent = new Event { Description = line };
            result.Add(currentEvent);
        }
        else if (line.StartsWith("#"))
        {
            currentEvent.Activities.Add(new Activity { Description = line });
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? How could I separate which activity goes on which Event? Also how could I load it on a repeater or gridview ? I want the user to preview and confirm before import this on the db tables.

Comment: With your regex, you lose the connection between events and activities. You could for example read the file using `File.ReadAllLines()` and iterate over the resulting array.

Comment: I dont have a file. I have textbox that puls the text from a database column nvarchar400. How can i use condition without regex? How the system will create "flags" for these characters?

Comment: Take a look at `foreach` and `string.Contains()`.

Comment: I know foreach statment(how could i use a List, if i didnt know foreach statment?...).Also i know string.Contains(). But how to create multiple arrays for every event? And how i will intent the activity arrays under every event list? It is a litle confusing...

Comment: @focus see edit. You'll have to improve the code yourself (add null-checks and trimming and all).